# Sign in with password when only PIN set up (Windows 11)

Tags: windows, security, windows-11, user-accounts, windows-hello

I recently bought a new computer which came with Windows 11. During setup the following options were selected:

- PIN (Windows Hello)
- Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options > Additional settings > For improved security, only allow Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts on this device > On

As far as I remember, no password was entered at any stage and none was requested for the local Administrator account. I do have a Windows account linked which I know the password for (tested by logging into the Microsoft accounts online). When the computer boots, a 4-digit pin is used to log in.

Now I want to disable the following task in Task Manager:

```
\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceDirectoryClient\RegisterDevicePeriodic24
```

Select `Disable` and a box pops up that the user account does not have permission to do this. The task is currently owned by `SYSTEM`. Right-click > `Properties` > `Security options` > `Change User or Group...`.

[image: Change user account]

After selecting my local administrator account (`abdek`), I click `OK` and my password is requested. No password I've tried works, including my (known working) Microsoft account password.

How do I provide a password to allow me to take ownership of this task? Is this related to `Windows HELLO`?

#### UPDATE

Have disabled `For improved security, only allow Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts on this device` and rebooted. After logging in (with my PIN), I still cannot take ownership of this task:

[image: User account unknown]

Comment: You need to create a password in Settings, Account.

Comment: I assume you have eliminated the possibility that your user simply doesn’t have the proper permissions, by default a new user account that is created, wouldn’t necessarily be an Administrator account

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into what I think is the same root problem today and thought I'd drop my fix here in case you haven't gotten yours figured out yet.

I was unable to connect to a network share created on my computer because it required a password and I had set up my computer using a PIN just as you did, along with the option to require a Windows Hello sign-in. Disabling the Windows Hello requirement didn't solve my issue by itself.

To make my Microsoft account password effective on my device, I had to click on the password option under Accounts -> Sign-in options (didn't have to enter anything, it just said "You're all set up"), then lock my screen and sign back in by clicking "Sign-in options" and using my password instead of my PIN. After signing in using my password, I could connect to the share on my computer using the same username and Microsoft account password I had been using the whole time.

Hope this helps!